# Filtering collapsed results in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index containing documents that represent entities at a given point in time. When an entity changes state, a new document is created with a timestamp. When I need to get the current state of all entities, I can do the following:

```
GET https://127.0.0.1:9200/myindex/_search
{
    "collapse": {
        "field": "entity_id"
    },
    "sort" : [{
        "timestamp": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }]
}
```

However, I would like to further filter the result of the collapse. When entities are deleted I create a new document that includes an is_deleted flag along with the timestamp in a nested metadata field. I would like to extend the above query to entirely filter out those entities that have been deleted. Using a term filter on `entity_metadata.is_deleted: true` obviously does not work, because then my result just includes the last document with that entity_id before it got marked as deleted. How can I filter my results *after* the collapse is done to exclude any tombstoned entites?

Comment: Instead of creating a tombstone document, why not updating all `entity_id` documents with an `is_deleted` flag set to true?

Comment: Reason is I'm using this index for event sourcing. So one of my use-cases is to be able to view the state of entities as of any date. I.e. If the entity is tombstoned at 2019-06-27, I would still like to be able to do an lte range filter on 2019-06-26 and see it as not deleted.

Comment: So instead of adding an `is_deleted` flag to all `entity_id` documents, you could add a `date_deleted` field with the date of the deletion, and then when you view a document, given its date and the `deleted_date` you'd know if the document was LIVE or deleted at that date. + it would allow you to consider 1) all documents that don't have a `deleted_date` field (i.e. not deleted) and 2) all documents that have a `deleted_date` before/after a given date.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that would work. I was hoping to avoid having to go back and update the previous documents, but if there's no way to do a post-collapse filter that is probably the best solution. (As an aside, think it's possible to achieve the filter after collapse using some sort of pipelined top_hits aggregation?)

Comment: Unfortunately, pipeline aggregations cannot work on `top_hits` results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is that instead of adding an `is_deleted` flag to all `entity_id` documents, you could add a `date_deleted` field with the date of the deletion to all documents of that entity, and then when you view a document, given its date and the `deleted_date` you'd know if the document was LIVE or deleted at that date.

In addition, it would allow you to consider:

1. all documents that don't have a `deleted_date` field (i.e. not deleted) and
2. all documents that have a `deleted_date` before/after a given date.